# Как вытащить информацию о лайке fb?

Tags: facebook-api

В ВК есть такое api - https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList

То есть, на странице site.ru/asd ставит лайк, потом я делаю запрос к вк и смотрю кто поставил.

Нужно тоже самое, только для фб, не могу найти апи.

То есть, нужно апи фб, в которое отправляется ссылка на страницу, на которой был поставлен лайк и в ответ возвращается список тех, кто поставил его.

Comment: вы написали что отправляется ссылка на страницу, это страница типа - публическая страница или страница где находится ОДИН пост?

Answer (score 1):

У FB API устроен не как у VK.

У facebook для всех видов записей разные id, поэтому для доступа к любому функционалу Вам надо знать id записи и название нужной API функции. В конкретном случае Вас интересует метод `/likes`.

Пример получения списка тех, кто лайкнул:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{id того, кто запостил}_{здесь_указываем_id_записи}/likes
```

Пример получения списка тех, кто лайкнул и количества лайков с поста на моей странице (это реальный пример, только без access_token):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/963586523696776_963070623748366/likes?summary=true
```

Ответ выглядит так:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "963586523696776"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "OTYzNTg2NTIzNjk2Nzc2",
      "before": "OTYzNTg2NTIzNjk2Nzc2"
    }
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1,
    "can_like": true,
    "has_liked": true
  }
}
```

`summary=true` отвечает за подсчёт количества лайков. Если его не укажете, то fb просто пришлёт список людей, которые лайкнули запись.

Comment: Я не знаю ни id записи, ни того кто запостил. Только url страницы.

Comment: @exec, у Вас вопрос сначала по-другому был записан или я чего попутал

Comment: видимо я не смог правильно описать. Итого, как решить вопрос? В ВК я отправляю app_id и hash ссылки, который отправляю на странице. В ФБ в виджет я отправляю полностью ссылку. Вот я нашел такое - http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.techlila.com но там показывает количество лайков, а мне нужно именно тех (одного) кто поставили лайк.

Comment: @exec, сейчас попробую что-нибудь придумать

Comment: ну как? Получилось?

Comment: @exec, увы, не нашёл

Comment: Возможно ли через клиента получать эти данные и отправлять на сервер? Из авторизации например?

Comment: @exec, наверное, как-то можно придумать. А Вам, собственно, зачем это?

Comment: Разработка для личных нужд.

Comment: а в самой ссылке нету ид записи и ид пользователя кто сделал этот пост?

Comment: вы написали что отправляется ссылка на страницу, это страница типа - публическая страница или страница где находится ОДИН пост?

Comment: @SkiesX, простите, немного не понял, не могли бы перефразировать Ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Umed второй вопрос я написал человеку который создал этот вопрос. просто не написал к кому я обращаюсь)

Comment: @SkiesX, про id-шники записи и пользователя. Если Вы хотите узнать сколько лайков у какой-то конкретной записи, значит Вы как-то нашли эту запись, значит уже знаете. А если Вы про то, что просто будучи на сайте fb можно ли получить эти id, то да, можно, id пользователя можно узнать зайдя на его страницу, а id записи наведя курсор на дату когда запостили (bid, по-моему)